# How to manage continuous UART transmission and reception on STM32?

Tags: stm32, usart

I have been struggling with serial communication via UART in STM32. I'm using TrueStudio and I want to communicate with a PC, which will send 7 bytes every 30ms and read 7 bytes every 10ms.

I tried receiving the bytes in the STM32 on interrupt mode. Every time the RX was not empty, the code should go to USART_Handler and then I used HAL_UART_Receive to get seven bytes. I know it doesn't look good, but it worked...

Then, to transmit the bytes to the PC, I used poll every 10ms (called HAL_UART_Transmit inside a timer interrupt), and it also worked. The problem is that when I try to make both transmission and reception together, there is loss of several bytes. I'm not sure how, but I believe the receive interrupt is messing up the transmission. Does anybody know what could be happening and have any sugestions on how to deal with this? Thank you already.

Comment: Please show us a minimal version of your code, otherwise we cannot help you. :)

Comment: Since you are using STMicro HAL, there are plenty of code examples provided by STMicro for basic use cases like UARt transmission. They are ready to use C projects for Keil, IAR or Eclipse and you can understand how the product works.